# setTimeout and UIEvent order

Tags: javascript, dom-events, settimeout, uievent, eventqueue

If a bunch of UIEvents are queued up because of some long-running method in a script, and at the end of the method I `setTimeout(myfunc, 0)`, what order will `myfunc` get called in relative to handlers for the previously queued events?  Is it guaranteed to be called after all previously queued events get handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most events in the browser are processed in FIFO order (first in, first out) via a central event queue.  Some UI events such as mousemove events are collapsed so you get the latest state, not necessarily all the in-between events.

So, the question is really when the mouse event gets into the JS event queue.  I wasn't really sure how this worked so I built a couple test demos.  What I found was that the answer depends.  If a UI event is what is hogging the JS Thread, then it looks like the other UI events don't get into the queue in front of the timer, but if the UI event finishes and some other action (not on the UI) hogs the CPU, then the evnets are queued in proper FIFO order.  So, it appears that "it depends" (in Chrome which is what I have tested so far).

I will post links to the demos in a second...

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xkjtwf8s/) shows that if the CPU hogging activity is not in response to a button click, then other button clicks that occur before the `setTimeout()` is schedule to fire will get processed before the `setTimeout()`:

```
long
click
click
click
timeout
```

But, [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zhLj9z2j/) where the CPU hogging happens in the button click event handler itself shows the opposite.  The clicks that happened before the `setTimeout()` was scheduled to fire did not get processed before it.

```
long
timeout
click
click
click
```

Now, I ran these both in Firefox and found that in both cases Firefox processes the events in FIFO order (in the order they actually happened).  For the second demo above, this is different than Chrome.

Now, I ran these both in IE and found that IE always processes the `setTimeout()` before the UI events - different than both Firefox and Chrome.

So, these tests show three different results in three different browsers.

Summarizing Results:

```
Browser      Hog CPU in Event Handler     Hog CPU after Event Handler
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Chrome 44       timeout first (not FIFO)        FIFO clicks first
Firefox 39      FIFO clicks first               FIFO clicks first
IE 11           timeout first (not FIFO)        timeout first (not FIFO)
```

---

For reference, here's the test case that hogs the CPU in the button click event handler:

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
    log("click");
});

document.getElementById("long").addEventListener("click", function() {
    log("long");
    setTimeout(function() {
        log("timeout");
    }, 1900)
    // hhog the CPU here before the event handler finishes
    var t = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - t < 2000) {}
});
```

And, here's the test case that hogs the CPU after the button client event handler has finished.

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
    log("click");
});

document.getElementById("long").addEventListener("click", function() {
    log("long");

    // schedule a setTimeout
    setTimeout(function() {
        log("timeout");
    }, 1900)

    // hog the CPU, but after the UI event has finished
    setTimeout(function() {
        // spin for 2 seconds to hog the JS thread
        var t = Date.now();
        while (Date.now() - t < 2000) {}
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: Wow, how weird.  So in other words it looks like in Chrome at least, UI event handlers block other UI events from getting inserted into the queue while they're running.

Comment: @Andy - it appears so unless there's some flaw in my test.  Something tells me there must be a part of some specification that talks about how this is supposed to work, but I haven't found it yet.  It could be one of the behaviors that is still not yet well specified.

Comment: right.  I hope the way Firefox behaves eventually becomes the specification

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little testing, I have to edit my answer because I was incorrect. Yes, UI events do take precedence over timeout. For timeout, it appears that no matter what order it is set up, UI events happen first.

Comment: But what about all the events that were queued **before** he called `setTimeout`, won't they be executed first?

Comment: Exactly @Barmar, that's what I was asking about.  Of course I know my timeout will be executed after the long running method.

Comment: In the test I ran, it did not seem to matter what order the timeout or events were set up in. Timeout was blocked by the UI events, so I edited my answer for accuracy.